# Sent data to view from controller not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I have this function in ** controller  **

```
function smsreq()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'Amount', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobileNo', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                echo "validated";
            } else { 
            $data = "<div>TEST</div>" ;
            $this->load->view('dashboard',$data); 
            }
    }
```

and in the ** view **

```
<?php echo $data ; ?>
```

But when the view,'dashboard' is loaded this is shown

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/dashboard.php

Line Number: 190
```

Why cant I pass the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass as array from controller to view.

```
$data["data"] = "<div>TEST</div>" ;
```